# Use hex byte in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10

This simple PowerShell script "fills in" the bad sectors of a USB flash drive. But I need to fill the drive with files containing 0x00 (all bits zero) and 0x255 (all bits 1). How can I use hex in PowerShell?

```
function filler {
    Param( [byte]$hex )

    $filearray = @()
    $count = 1
    $freespace = Get-PSDrive H
    $maxfiles = [int]($freespace.Free / 1048576)

    do {
        $randomnum = Get-Random -Minimum 100000000 -Maximum 999999999

        "$hex" * 1048576 | Out-File $randomnum

        $filecontent = Get-Content $randomnum -Raw

        if ($filecontent -notcontains ('$hex')) {
            # do nothing because the content is incorrect
        } else {
            $filearray += $randomnum
        }

        $count++
    } while ($count -le $maxfiles)

    foreach ($filename in $filearray) {
        Remove-Item $filename
    }
}

filler -hex 0x00
filler -hex 0xFF
```

Comment: `[byte]$hex = 0xff; "$hex" * 5` doesn't do what you seem to expect. It creates the string "255255255255255" (repeat the string representation of the integer value 0xFF 5 times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The string `"0x00"` is different from the numeric value represented by `0x00`.**

Make sure you specify `-Encoding Byte` when trying to read and write raw data to/from files:

```
,$hex * 1048576 | Set-Content $randomnum -Encoding Byte
```

And, similarly when reading from files:

```
$filecontent = Get-Content $randomnum -Encoding Byte
if($filecontent |Where-Object {$_ -notin @(0x00,0xFF)}){
    # do nothing
}
```

Comment: `Out-File`: `-Encoding Byte` not exist. Used others but fills file more than 1MB. `Get-Content`: Should be `-Encoding Byte`.

Comment: @BillPaxtonn That's what I get for trying to write answers on my phone :-P Updated the answer